# Fixed menu position

Tags: css

I have a fixed menu on top, and I would like to center it, the red box should be inside the orange one:

[code in the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jnkhbhuc/)

```
<?php    
header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");  
?>

body {
padding:0;
margin:0;
background-image:url('../Images/web_background.png');
background-repeat:repeat;
background-position:right top;
background-attachment:fixed;
background-size:100%;
}

header, footer, section, nav
{
display:blocks;
border: 10px solid blue;
}

.header{
height: 250px;
padding-top: 43px;
border: 10px solid navy;

}

.container
{
border: 1px black solid;
margin: 0 auto;
width:950px; 
border: 10px solid green;

}


.navigation{
height: 100px;
border: 10px solid purple;
}


.content{
height: auto;
min-height: 500px;
overflow: hidden;
border: 10px solid fushia;

}

.navTop
{
width:100%;
position: fixed; 
top: 0px;
right: 0px;
left:0;
border: 10px solid yellow;

}


.nav {
background-color: #EEEEEE;
max-width: 950px;
/*max-height: 40px;*/
min-width: 700px;
min-height: 40px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
border:1px solid #ccc;
box-shadow:6px 6px 12px #888;
-moz-box-shadow: 6px 6px 12px #888; 
-webkit-box-shadow: 6px 6px 12px #888;
border-radius:0px 0px 5px 5px;
-moz-border-radius:0px 0px 5px 5px;
-webkit-border-radius:0px 0px 5px 5px;
text-align: center;
border: 10px solid orange;


}

.inliner {
list-style-type: none;
float: right;
display: inline-block; 
}


.inlinerTop {
width: 120px;
height: 50px;
margin-top: -15px;
background-color: red;
border: 10px solid rose;
```

}

HTML:

```
<div class="navTop">
<div class="nav"><ul><li class="inliner inlinerTop">
<a href="Vehicules.html">Véhicules</a></li><li class="inliner inlinerTop">
<a href="Estate.html">Immobilier</a></li><li class="inliner inlinerTop">
<a href="HighTech.html">High-Tech</a></li><li class="inliner inlinerTop">
<a href="House.html">Maison</a></li><li class="inliner inlinerTop">
<a href="Services.html">Services</a></li><li class="inliner inlinerTop">
<a href="Others.html">Autres</a></li><li class="inliner inlinerTop">
<a href="FashionWoman.html">Fashion</a></li><li class="inliner inlinerTop">
<a href="Beauty.html">Beauté</a></li><li class="inliner inlinerTop">
<a href="Leasure.html">Loisirs</a></li></ul></div>
```

I am looking for a centered menu inside boxes, each item is inside a box.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I just paste the code part only, I could not paste all the code, the full code is on the fiddle

Comment: the full code is here http://jsfiddle.net/jnkhbhuc/1/

Comment: I added my code to my question above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/jnkhbhuc/2/ (CSS modifications at the end)

There's a large gap for several reasons, the most significant of which is that you're `float`ing the items `right` so they're breaking onto a new line while aligning to the right. You should `float: left` your `li` elements instead. That still leaves a bit of padding to the left, the default behaviour for `ul`s that can be fixed with `padding: 0`. But then your `li`s are still too wide, which can be fixed with `width: 11.11%;` (100% / 9 items).

*Note: An interesting result of `float`ing `right` is that the items will appear in reversed order. That's because the items are being laid out from right to left. You can still `float: right` with `width: 11.11%` if you actually did want them to appear in reversed order.*

Comment: I added a splitter between each word, and adjust the width to 10%, but after the last word "Loisirs", I a having a huge space, I don't is due to what, http://jsfiddle.net/jnkhbhuc/9/

Comment: That's because each item's width is 10%. 9 x 10% = 90%, plus the splitter width. In the [standard box model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box_model), the border is not included in an element's width, which is why the elements wouldn't fit with 11.11% width plus the additional border (as you've probably discovered). One quick and dirty workaround is to set `box-sizing: border-box;` to change this behaviour.

Comment: I changed it to width: 11.11%; and the last element returned back to a new line http://jsfiddle.net/jnkhbhuc/10/

Comment: Yep, this is because of the added width of the border. See my comment above. Switching to `box-sizing: border-box;` will make the elements have 11.11% width, including the border. http://jsfiddle.net/jnkhbhuc/11/

Answer (score 0):

Your floats are not contained try doing.

```
nav {overflow:hidden}
```

or a add a [clearfix](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/) class to contain the floats

Comment: My question is why there is a space between on the left of the red box inside the orange box, the orange box should contain the red box, if I add overflow, see the result http://jsfiddle.net/jnkhbhuc/1/